# Java code: Cant move JButtons in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I have been following a tutorial, its a little old, 1.6 Java, I use 1.8. So something has changed, heres my code:

```
private int width = 600;
private int height = 400;

private int lHeight = 4;

private int bWidth = 80;
private int bHeight = 40;

private int lItemWidth = 5;

private JPanel window = new JPanel();
private JButton play, options, help, updatenotes, quit;
private Rectangle rplay, roptions, rhelp, rupdatenotes, rquit;

public Launcher() {
    try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setTitle("Launcher - Final frontier");
    setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(window);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);

    drawButtons();
}

private void drawButtons() {
    play = new JButton("Play");
    rplay = new Rectangle(0, 0, bWidth, bHeight);
    play.setBounds(rplay);
    window.add(play);

}
```

When I change rplay's x position, y position, width, or height nothing happens. It stays centered to the center of the screen and I cant figure it out.

- BTW public Launcher is being called from the main method in a different class.

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: By reading the help files. I've done it mostly for you this time, but in the future, please read the help files of any site you post to --- that's why they're there. Link: [SO Editor Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @TJGames by pressing control+shift+f in eclipse if you are editing there

Comment: Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  Your button is under the control of a layout manager

Comment: You're going to want to learn about and use the Swing layout managers to best solve your component placement issues.

Comment: or by pasting the code in Stack's editor, highlighting it all then pressing CTRL-K ;-) it will indent it. No need to use the `>` character.

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do I make it not under the control of a layout, or just move it easily?

Comment: @TJGames No, no it's not. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Ok, so I can't just make buttons with JButtons. So, could I use mouse position if statements? Would that be easier, or more effecient?

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't have a line of code need to stop it from parenting to a layout manager.

```
window.setLayout(null);
```

in

```
public Launcher() {
    try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setTitle("Launcher - Final frontier");
    setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(window);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);

    //Here
    window.setLayout(null);

    drawButtons();
}
```